# Image - preimage equality in a commutative diagram

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f:X \to Y, q:Y \to W, p:X \to Z$ and $g: Z \to W$, be functions satisfying $q \circ f = g \circ p$ (for clarity I've attached a commutative diagram of this down bellow).

Does the following statement hold:

For every subset $S \subseteq Z$ it is true that $$q^{-1}(g(S)) = f(p^{-1}(S)).$$

I've tried showing this using elementary inclusions, but it got complicated really quickly with all the symbols, so I'm looking for a more elegant approach.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lBPg.jpg

Comment: Shouldn't it be $q \circ f=g \circ p$?

Comment: Try thinking about the case when the inverse image of S under p is empty (also one of your compositions is the wrong way round)

Answer (score 1):

The result is NOT true.

**Hint:**

Take $X=\{1,2,3\}, Y=\{a,b\}, Z=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $W=\{c,d\}$.

Let

$1,2 \xrightarrow{f}a$ and $3 \xrightarrow{f}b$ AND $1 \xrightarrow{p}1, \quad 2 \xrightarrow{p}2$ and $3 \xrightarrow{p}3$.

$1,2,4 \xrightarrow{g}c$ and $ 3 \xrightarrow{g}d$  AND $1 \xrightarrow{p}1, \quad a \xrightarrow{q}c$ and $b \xrightarrow{q}d$.

Now let $S=\{4\} \subset Z$ and see what happens.